# Replace 4-5 lines of a large text file using python

Tags: python, string

I have a text file in which i need to change

USER PROMPT [Program SIM GENTEST05]

```
    <Description />
    <MultiPartMessage>false</MultiPartMessage>
    <NumberOfMultiParts>0</NumberOfMultiParts>
    <Commented>false</Commented>
    <ProgrammingCmdData xsi:type="UserPromptData">
      <Prompt>Program SIM GENTEST05</Prompt>
```

with some customize values. 
I need some hint to do it in python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) library, it would be something like this:

```
import sys
import fileinput

for i, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('lorem_ipsum.txt', inplace=1)):
    if "<MultiPartMessage>" in line:
        sys.stdout.write(line.replace(
            '<MultiPartMessage>false</MultiPartMessage>', 
            '<MultiPartMessage>something</MultiPartMessage>'))
    elif "<NumberOfMultiParts>" in line:
        sys.stdout.write(line.replace(
            '<NumberOfMultiParts>0</NumberOfMultiParts>', 
            '<NumberOfMultiParts>something</NumberOfMultiParts>'))
    else
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```